# Cannot find module main-server.js

Tags: angular, angular2-template, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have this error after created a new angular component, after created I defined it on app.module.shared.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { HistoryGridComponent } from "./components/history/histories-grid.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HistoryGridComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'history', component: HistoryGridComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

And tried to run, but it always returns the follow error:

[image: Error]

Any ideas about what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you deleted your history-grid.component.html in the history-grid folder. If you did that delete the "templateUrl" property in @Component of your history-component.ts
[image]

Comment: No, the html page is in my project folder.